# Trying to split by two delimiters and it doesn't work - C

Tags: c, string, split

I wrote below code to readin line by line from stdin ex.

```
city=Boston;city=New York;city=Chicago\n
```

and then split each line by ';' delimiter and print each record.
Then in yet another loop I try to split the record by '=' delimiter to get to the actual values. But for some reason then the main (first) loop doesn't loop beyond the first iteration, why?

```
char*   del1 = ";";
char*   del2 = "=";
char    input[BUFLEN];

while(fgets(input, BUFLEN, fp)) {

        input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';
        char* record = strtok(input, &del1);

        while(record) {
                printf("Record: %s\n",record);

                char*  field = strtok(record, &del2);
                while(field) {
                     printf("Field: %s\n",field);
                     field = strtok(NULL, &del2);
                }

                record = strtok(NULL, &del1);
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't mean to take the address of 'del1' and 'del2' -- they're already char *.

Comment: yes you're right, I retyped it incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things: first, this line is not very good:

```
 input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';
```

fgets() always finish with '\0' and this will give weird results with your input isn't finished exactly at '\n'.

Second, strtok() cannot be called two times concurrently. For that, use strtok_r(), which recieves a char** as a third argument to store the state.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to use the re-entrant form of strtok, strtok_r because when you are calling strtok inside your loop, it's wiping out the string for the outside loop.  When you call record = strtok(NULL), it is trying to parse your inside string again.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use two loop of strtok because the strtok is storing globally the pointer in your string.

Your would have to do a loop to separate the `;`, store those results and one loop to separate the `=` on the previously stored result.

```
char*   del1 = ";";
char*   del2 = "=";
char    input[BUFLEN];
char*   tokens[255]; // have to be careful not to go more then that
while(fgets(input, BUFLEN, fp)) {

    // input[strlen(input)-1]='\0'; // you don't need that fgets add the NULL
    char* record = strtok(input, del1);
    i = 0;
    while(record) {

            tokens[i++] = strdup(record);  
            record = strtok(NULL, del1);
    }
    for(v = 0; v < i; v++){
      char*  field = strtok(token[v], del2);
      while(field) {
          printf("Record: %s\n",token[v]);
          printf("Field: %s\n",field);
          field = strtok(NULL, del2);
      }
    }
}
```

please note you have to `free` all strdup strings after or you are going to create a memory leak.

also please not the signature of `strtok` is

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

so you don't need the `&del` since del is already a `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is happening:

- user input:  `a=1;b=2;c=3\n`
- after *fgets*:  `a=1;b=2;c=3\0`
- 1st call to *strtok(non-NULL, ...)*:  `a=1\0b=2;c=3\0`
- 2nd call to *strtok(non-NULL, ...)*:  `a\01\0b=2;c=3\0`

*strtok* keeps a bit of state when it is first invoked with a non-NULL *str* argument, so it can remember how long the string was (or, equivalently, where in memory it ends), **because it mangles the string thereafter, replacing delimiters with NULLs**.

When you call *strtok* again with a non-NULL argument, that single place where state is kept is overwritten with what *strtok* perceives to be a new string of 3 characters and a NULL (`a=1\0`), since *strtok* can no longer remember the original input characteristics.  So, *record* is set to NULL at the end of the loop on the first iteration, because *strtok* thinks it's at the end of its (much shorter than intended!) input string.

Check out `strtok_r`.